# Cost Model of the Quick-Find algorithm

Tags: java

I am taking the lesson of Algorithm Part I in Coursera.
And This is the problem.

In this PPT he said `Connected` need 2 array accesses, and `Union` need 2N+2 array accesses
[image]

But in the next PPT, he said `Union` need N array accesses, and `Find` need 1.

I am confused about why they are not the same.

[image]

Comment: It says *at most 2N + 2*, I believe on average it's just N, but I'm not positive.

Comment: I believe the cost model is stated in implicit O notation. So 1 stands for an arbitrary constant and N for an arbitrary linear function depending on N.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Sorry, I am new to the programming world, don't understand what is  _implicit O notation_ . Could you give me a exact webpage that have a explanation of _implicit O notation_?

Comment: [implicit](http://www.dict.cc/?s=implicit) and [O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) basically you say, that if you multiply the content of O(n) by a Constant you have an upper bound for your function. O(n) means your program runs approximitately in c*n, with an arbitrary c. This tells you about the scaling of your programm for bigger systems/datasets.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Thanks, you solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

In find you just look at the 2 array item and see if they equal while the union requires you to go through the entire array and change the ids.